# Multiple Definition of a function in C, Prototyping

Tags: c, function, definition, prototyping

Eclipse tells me that I have mutliple Definitions of a function.
I just can't spot the mistake.
This is my main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "kontaktverzeichnis.h"


int main(){

    kontakt_hinzufuegen();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the header:

```
#ifndef KONTAKTVERZEICHNIS_H_
#define KONTAKTVERZEICHNIS_H_
#include "kontaktfunktionen.c"

int kontakt_hinzufuegen();


#endif /* KONTAKTVERZEICHNIS_H_ */
```

and this is kontaktfunktionen.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

kontakt[];


kontakt_hinzufuegen(){
int i = 0;
printf("Bisher sind %i Kontakte angelegt.",kontakt[i]);

    kontakt[i++];

}

struct kontaktname{
    char* name;
    char* vorname;
};

struct kontaktanschrift{
    char* strasse;
    int hausnummer;
    int plz;
    char* ort;
    char* land;

};
```

Where is my error?

Comment: I can't help but notice that `kontakt_hinzufuegen()` lacks a return type in `kontaktfunktionen.c`

Comment: Why do you do: `#include "kontaktfunktionen.c"`. Headers are to be included, not source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not `#include` anything in your header file. And do a `#include "kontaktverzeichnis.h"` in the `kontaktfunktionen.c` file.

As @StoryTeller commented, define your `kontakt_hinzufuegen()` as `int kontakt_hinzufuegen()` in the `kontaktfunktionen.c` file and return an `int` value from the function `kontakt_hinzufuegen` as for ex::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "kontaktverzeichnis.h"

// define the type for this array as below
int kontakt[];


int kontakt_hinzufuegen(){
 int i = 0;
 printf("Bisher sind %i Kontakte angelegt.",kontakt[i]);

 kontakt[i++];

 // Return an int value
 return 0 ;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're not supposed to `#include` C files, that's not the proper way to organize your code.

You should compile the C files separately and then link them together, or compile them all at once with a single compiler invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that in `kontaktfunktionen.h` you are including `kontaktfunktionen.c`. This will include all the definitions and declarations from `kontaktfunktionen.c` which are already declared when you use `kontaktfunktionen.c`

As others have said: You **should not** include `.c` files in your header files.